# D3- Update bar graph's x-axis range with slider

Tags: d3.js

Right now I have a csv file that contains a wide range of data points that I am displaying in a stacked bar chart. The thing that is giving me problems is I want to be able to control the range of the values displayed on the x-axis dynamically with a slider.

i.e. changing the slider from 1 -> 5 will now only display bars of data greater than 5.

I have an update function that handles the changing of the slider value and will even dynamically change the labels for the x-axis but the bars themselves aren't changing...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.x.axis line {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

</style>

<p>
  <label for="nMedals" 
         style="display: inline-block; width: 240px; text-align: right">
         Total Medals = <span id="nMedals-value">…</span>
  </label>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="50" id="nMedals">
</p>

<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 85, left: 40},
    width = 1160 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#EAC530", "#c0c0c0", "#cd7f32"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>" + d.medals[0].name + ":</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + d.medals[0].y1 + "</span>" + 
    "<br/><strong>" + d.medals[1].name + ":</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + (d.medals[1].y1 - d.medals[0].y1) + "</span>" +
    "<br/><strong>" + d.medals[2].name + ":</strong> <span style='color:white'>" + (d.medals[2].y1 - d.medals[1].y1) + "</span>";
  })

var filterMedals = 0;

d3.select("#nMedals").on("input", function(){
  update(+this.value);
});

function update(nMedals){
  d3.select("#nMedals-value").text(nMedals);
  d3.select("#nMedals").property("value", nMedals);

  filterMedals = nMedals;

  //get data again
  d3.csv("data/Olympics.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Country" && key !== "TotalMedals"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.medals = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.medals[d.medals.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  //Put all countries with more than 5 medals in the x-axis
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { if (d.TotalMedals > filterMedals) return d.Country; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);


  //select area we want to change
  var svg = d3.select("body").transition();

  //make changes
  svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .selectAll("text")  
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("dx", "-.8em")
      .attr("dy", ".15em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "rotate(-65)" 
          });

  //Do whatever to the bars
    var country = svg.selectAll(".Country")
      .data(data)
      .filter(function(d) { return d.total > filterMedals })

    country.enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Country) + ",0)"; })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

    country.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.medals; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      //puts bars on the bottom x-axis
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      //Does the coloring of the bars
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    country.exit().remove()


  }); 
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis)
      .append("text")
      .text("Countries")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate(" + -.75 * margin.left + ", " + margin.bottom * .5 + ")";});

svg.call(tip);

d3.csv("data/Olympics.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "Country" && key !== "TotalMedals"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.medals = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.medals[d.medals.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  //Put all countries with more than 5 medals in the x-axis
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { if (d.TotalMedals > filterMedals) return d.Country; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  //Puts the name of the countries on the x-axis
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")


  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Medals");

  var country = svg.selectAll(".Country")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("g")
      //moves bars along x-axis
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.Country) + ",0)"; })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

  country.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.medals; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      //puts bars on the bottom x-axis
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      //Does the coloring of the bars
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });


  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

  update(0);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Break down your enter-update-delete as follow:

```
var medals = country.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) { return d.medals; })
  .enter();
medals.append("rect");

medals.attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  //puts bars on the bottom x-axis
  .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
  .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
  //Does the coloring of the bars
  .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

country.exit().remove()
```

The way you did it, your attributes and styles only get applied to your newly created rectangles.